# How to instantiate object using iterable in Python?

Tags: python, python-class

I need to instantiate an object using iterable with multiple objects inside. I have to create another method to do it

```
class MyClass:

  def __init__(self, *args):
    self.args = args

  def instantiate_from_iterable
     #some clever code
```

I need to have a result like this

```
MyClass.instantiate_from_iterable([1, 5, 3]) == MyClass(1, 5, 3)

MyClass.instantiate_from_iterable((3, 1, 7)) == MyClass(3, 1, 7)
```

I have no idea how to do this. If someone could help, I would appreciate it very much!

Comment: Could you provide an (abstract) example of what the result of such an instantiation would be? So how are the multiple objects inside the outtermost object positioned (nested, ...)?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour]. Your question covers the same topics as some existing ones, so I've closed it accordingly, but if there's some subtlety I'm missing, LMK (like for example, `MyClass.__eq__()` is undefined, so I'm assuming it'd be implemented as `self.args == other.args`). For more tips, check out [How to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`classmethod`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod) is what what you're after:

```py
from collections.abc import Iterable

class MyClass:
    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args
   
    @classmethod
    def instantiate_from_iterable(cls, args: Iterable):
        return cls(*args)

    
a = MyClass(1, 5, 7)
b = MyClass.instantiate_from_iterable([1, 5, 7])
     
print(a.args)  # -> (1, 5, 7)
print(b.args)  # -> (1, 5, 7)
```

Comment: `Iterable` is a generic, so it should have a type parameter, shouldn't it? I think `Iterable[object]` would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you would like to do.

Try the following:

```py
class MyClass:

    def __init__(self, *args):
        self.args = args

    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, MyClass):
            return False
        else:
            return self.args == other.args

assert MyClass(1, 5, 3) == MyClass(*[1, 5, 3])
```

There would be no need for a clever function. Just unpack the list with the `*` before the list or tuple.
You would make the object comparably using the magic function `__eq__` to make them comparable.